# Selectize.js items overflow input width

Tags: jquery, selectize.js

when adding long items to a Selectize input, the input grows taller, in my case overlaying other input below:

[image]

**How can I make the items get rendered on the right, keeping the input height?** I found this plugin:
[NoWrap Plugin](http://www.benbybenjacobs.com/blog/2014/04/09/no-wrap-plugin-for-selectize-dot-js)

But to be honest I couldn't get it working, maybe because he uses LESS, or I dont know what to do. I'm rendering only e-mails and creating items on the fly using the exact code of their page:

```
var REGEX_EMAIL = '([a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&\'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@' +
                  '(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?)';

$('#select-to').selectize({
    persist: false,
    maxItems: null,
    valueField: 'email',
    labelField: 'name',
    searchField: ['name', 'email'],
    options: [
        {email: 'brian@thirdroute.com', name: 'Brian Reavis'},
        {email: 'nikola@tesla.com', name: 'Nikola Tesla'},
        {email: 'someone@gmail.com'}
    ],
    render: {
        item: function(item, escape) {
            return '<div>' +
                (item.name ? '<span class="name">' + escape(item.name) + '</span>' : '') +
                (item.email ? '<span class="email">' + escape(item.email) + '</span>' : '') +
            '</div>';
        },
        option: function(item, escape) {
            var label = item.name || item.email;
            var caption = item.name ? item.email : null;
            return '<div>' +
                '<span class="label">' + escape(label) + '</span>' +
                (caption ? '<span class="caption">' + escape(caption) + '</span>' : '') +
            '</div>';
        }
    },
    createFilter: function(input) {
        var match, regex;

        // email@address.com
        regex = new RegExp('^' + REGEX_EMAIL + '$', 'i');
        match = input.match(regex);
        if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[0]);

        // name <email@address.com>
        regex = new RegExp('^([^<]*)\<' + REGEX_EMAIL + '\>$', 'i');
        match = input.match(regex);
        if (match) return !this.options.hasOwnProperty(match[2]);

        return false;
    },
    create: function(input) {
        if ((new RegExp('^' + REGEX_EMAIL + '$', 'i')).test(input)) {
            return {email: input};
        }
        var match = input.match(new RegExp('^([^<]*)\<' + REGEX_EMAIL + '\>$', 'i'));
        if (match) {
            return {
                email : match[2],
                name  : $.trim(match[1])
            };
        }
        alert('Invalid email address.');
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Just answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49471602/how-can-i-set-the-selectize-js-multiple-select-input-field-to-always-be-a-single/59638654#59638654.  FYI to admins - possible duplicate question here with the one in my URL.