# How can I set the Selectize.js multiple select input field to always be a single line?

Tags: jquery, css, selectize.js

I have an Selectize.js multi input field, that has a fixes height and width. 
When I select several values, the field places the selected values into multiple lines, making the previous values hidden to the user.

Is there any way I can force selectize to always place the values in a single line without going into a new line?

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem, ended up being a simple CSS fix:

```
<style>
    .selectize-input { white-space: nowrap !important; }
</style>
```

This will turn off the wordwrap and keep everything on a single line.  Just implemented and will adjust this answer if I run into anything, but hopefully it helps.